# how to determine the expected prompt_tokens for gpt-4 chatCompletion

Tags: openai-api, chatgpt-api, gpt-4

For the following nodejs code below I am getting prompt_tokens = 24 in the response. I want to be able to determine what the expected prompt_tokens should be prior to making the request.

```js
    import { Configuration, OpenAIApi } from 'openai';

    const configuration = new Configuration({
        apiKey: process.env.OPENAI_API_KEY,
     });
     
    const openai = new OpenAIApi(configuration);

    const completion = await openai.createChatCompletion({
    model: "gpt-4",
    messages: [
      {role: "system", content: systemPrompt}, //systemPrompt= 'You are a useful assistant.'     
      {role: "user", content: userPrompt} //userPrompt= `What is the meaning of life?`
    ]
    });

    /* completion.data = {
       id: 'chatcmpl-72Andnl250jsvSJGbjBJ6YzzFGToA',
       object: 'chat.completion',
       created: 1680752525,
       model: 'gpt-4-0314',
       usage: { prompt_tokens: 24, completion_tokens: 91, total_tokens: 115 },
       choices: [ [Object] ]
    } */
```

It seems like each model has its own way of encoding and the best lib for that is python tiktoken. Hence if I was to estimate "prompt_tokens". I would need to pass through the "text" value to the script below. However I am not sure what I should be using as the "text" below in the python script for the "messages" above in the nodejs, such that print(token_count) below = 24 [the actual prompt_tokens in the response]

```py
    import sys
    import tiktoken

    text = sys.argv[1]
    enc = tiktoken.encoding_for_model("gpt-4")
    tokens = enc.encode(text)
    token_count = len(tokens)
    print(token_count)
```

Answer (score -1):

OpenAI recommends a JS library [gpt3-encoder](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gpt-3-encoder), after testing it gives similar results to their [tokenizer playground](https://platform.openai.com/tokenizer).

Here is an example on how to use it:

```js
import { encode, decode } from 'gpt-3-encoder'

const str = 'This is an example sentence to try encoding out on!'
const encoded = encode(str)
console.log('Encoded this string looks like: ', encoded)
```

Which gives the following result:

```js
Encoded this string looks like:  [
  1212,   318, 281,
  1672,  6827, 284,
  1949, 21004, 503,
   319,     0
]
```

If you want to find the correspondence from a token id to the string using

```js
for (let token of encoded) {
  console.log({ token, string: decode([token]) })
}
```

result

```
{ token: 1212, string: 'This' }
{ token: 318, string: ' is' }
{ token: 281, string: ' an' }
{ token: 1672, string: ' example' }
...
```

And finally, to turn token ids back, the sentence

```js
const decoded = decode([array of token ids])
console.log('We can decode it back into:\n', decoded)
```

So for you, you can look a the size of the `encoded` array, to get the number of token. `encoded.length`

Comment: The original question is about determining the number of prompt tokens for ChatCompletion api which takes an array of strings. The example you provide is for a single string. Simply concatenating into a single string does not yield an accurate results